# Flutter: Hive database updating and copying

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I want to use Hive as the database for my Flutter app. After looking through the sparse documentation and trying to find information online, I have the following questions:

1. When the app is updated I need to have the databases in the new version overwrite the databases that are already on the device. The type adapter won’t change, the new databases will just have extra items.
2. I need to copy all the items from one database to another (empty) database with the same type adapter.

Assistance will be really appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by extra items, if you mean you will have new models or changes in the models then it will be handled automatically by hive, but if you want some static data to be in the app then just store the data in a json file and store it as an asset and add it to the database at the start of the app

Comment: Models won’t change. Whats the point of using a database if you are going to store the data as json?

Comment: I think you simply add new models to the database; if that is the case, you won't need to do anything because Hive will automatically add the new models to the old database.